# Как организовать доступ пользователей к БД?

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server, entity-framework, клиент-сервер

Доброго времени суток!

Подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше организовать доступ к данным в БД пользователям из приложения, при этом исключая возможность менять что-либо в БД напрямую (например через MS SQL Server Managment Studio) ?

Входные данные следующие:
Есть приложение на C# WinForms+EF (клиент), работающий с БД MS SQL
Есть БД MS SQL

Нужно сделать возможным делать изменения в БД пользователям только из приложения. При этом пользователи должны авторизироваться в клиенте под своими учетными данными (для возможности отслеживания их действий).

Какие могут быть варианты?
Если сделать "технического" пользователя для выполнения действий с БД, а авторизироваться под учетными данным пользователя, то прошу помочь с примером и описать как это реализовать.

P.S. Взаимодействие БД и клиента через Web service или Windows service реализовать не могу в виду отсутствия возможности.

Comment: В БД mssql весьма богатые возможности по установке прав пользователей. Уж что-что а ограничивать в правах в микрософт умеют. А чтобы только через приложение, то варианта два. Один защита от дурака - не ставить пользователю MS SQL Server Managment Studio, другой - это многозвенная техника. Не знаю работает ли Entity таким образом, но вполне может быть.

Comment: А как это инфраструктурно организовано? БД находится у пользователя локально, или располагается где-то удалённо, куда пользователь может подключиться через приложение либо через SSMS?

Comment: @i-one БД находится на сервере, у пользователя есть mssql (студия), проблема в том, что я не могу найти пример, как сделать так, чтобы через приложение была возможность работать с данными, а через mssql (студия) не было. Пока я додумался только выдавать права на базу в части назначения ролей пользователям в mssql (студия). В таком случае работа из приложения возможна, но и руками через студию можно снести что угодно.

Comment: Можно попробовать следующее (хотя, конечно, это всё не слишком правильно, и, думаю не спасёт от целенаправленного взлома). У каждого пользователя должен быть логин в БД с соответствующими установленными правами, но пароль пользователь знать не должен. Пароль (в зашифрованном виде) получать, выполняя какую-нибудь процедуру в БД из под другого "технического" логина (которому кроме этого ничего не доступно), предоставляя "пароль от пароля логина", затем приложение расшифровывает пароль ключом (ключ зашит в приложении и пользователю неизвестен) и пересоединяется к БД уже требуемым логином.

Comment: @i-one Спасибо, хорошая идея. Нашел первичное решение в изменении вида ConnectionString (сразу не додумался ставить авторизацию по логину-паролю "технического пользователя"). Таким образом у непосредственных пользователей будут права только на чтение (выдам через БД), а на любые изменения будут права только у "технического" пользователя, под которым будет работать программа. Не могу утверждать что это хорошее решение, но скрыв логин и пароль из Connection String получится простая, но все таки защита от изменения данных в БД (я понимаю что защита слабая). Ваше решение буду реализовывать далее.

Comment: В общем случае, в такой постановке задача не решается. Единственное, на что тут может ориентироваться сервер, это на свойство подключения "Application Name". Но ничего не мешает в той же SSMS при подключении задать этот параметр произвольным образом, в том числе и таким, как у Вашей программы.

Comment: Оптимальный вариант - использовать Application Roles. Есть еще пара способов: 1. сделать простейший REST-сервис (имхо самый надежный и правильный вариант) 2. зашифровать файл со строкой соединения. Если пользователь не будет снифить трафик - ни логин ни пароль ему не достать. Кстати еще вариант - можете попробовать поиграть с портом для соединения, если поставить нестандартный мало кто догадается как подключится.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что вам нужно что-то в этом дуже:
В MS SQL Server есть так называемые Application Roles - по сути механизм передачи контроля за правами приложению.
См. вот здесь: [ALTER APPLICATION ROLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188900(v=sql.120).aspx)